# star rating how to enable if a star is clicked the previous are clicked too

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.ratings_stars').click(function() {
  $('.ratings_stars').removeClass('selected'); // Removes the selected class from all of them
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  var rating = $(this).data('rating'); // Get the rating from the selected star

  $('#rating').val(rating); // Set the value of the hidden rating form element
});
```

```css
fa-star {
  color: rgba(112, 111, 111, 0.856);
}

.fa-star:hover {
  color: #e2334c;
}

.fa-star.selected {
  color: #001628;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="rating" name="rating" value="-1">
<div class="rating">
  <i class="ratings_stars fa fa-star" data-rating="1"></i>
  <i class="ratings_stars fa fa-star" data-rating="2"></i>
  <i class="ratings_stars fa fa-star" data-rating="3"></i>
  <i class="ratings_stars fa fa-star" data-rating="4"></i>
  <i class="ratings_stars fa fa-star" data-rating="5"></i>
</div>
```

When one star is clicked the other previous before it doesn't get clicked but it saves correctly to the database.

Comment: what is the html?

Comment: i updated the code

Comment: Use a for loop, and iterate -1 each time, adding the `selected` class.

Comment: Hows about... don't click them all? simply apply the filled style to them.

Answer (score 2):

use [`prevAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/) and [`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextall/)

```js
$('.rating').on('click', '.ratings_stars', function () {
  var star = $(this)
  star.addClass('selected')
  star.prevAll().addClass('selected')
  star.nextAll().removeClass('selected')
  $('#rating').val(star.data('rating'))
});
```

```css
.fa-star {
  color: rgba(112, 111, 111, 0.856);
}

.fa-star:hover {
  color: #e2334c;
}

.fa-star.selected {
  color: #001628;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="rating" name="rating" value="-1">
<div class="rating">
  <i class="ratings_stars fa fa-star" data-rating="1"></i>
  <i class="ratings_stars fa fa-star" data-rating="2"></i>
  <i class="ratings_stars fa fa-star" data-rating="3"></i>
  <i class="ratings_stars fa fa-star" data-rating="4"></i>
  <i class="ratings_stars fa fa-star" data-rating="5"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: well it works here so what is different? I can not guess why it does not work unless you can give me more details on why. Is the mark up different? Is the event listener being bound correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution without any jQuery:

```js
const stars = document.querySelectorAll('.ratings_stars');

document.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains('ratings_stars')) {
    let clicktargetReached = false;
    for (const star of stars) {
      star.classList[clicktargetReached ? 'remove' : 'add']('selected');
      if (star === evt.target) {
        clicktargetReached = true;
      }
    }
    result.textContent = evt.target.dataset.rating;
  }
});
```

```css
fa-star {
  color: rgba(112, 111, 111, 0.856);
}

.fa-star:hover {
  color: #e2334c;
}

.fa-star.selected {
  color: #a00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="rating">
  <i class="ratings_stars fa fa-star" data-rating="1"></i>
  <i class="ratings_stars fa fa-star" data-rating="2"></i>
  <i class="ratings_stars fa fa-star" data-rating="3"></i>
  <i class="ratings_stars fa fa-star" data-rating="4"></i>
  <i class="ratings_stars fa fa-star" data-rating="5"></i>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This demo leverages index position of each star. The hover effect is pure CSS:

- Assign `display: flex` to parent tag of stars
- Reverse the order of the stars and assign the `order` property in reverse order as well.
- Keep in mind the ternary condition is reversed as well (line A)
- Add this CSS ruleset to the original `:hover` ruleset

  ```
  .star:hover~.star
  ```

```js
$('.rating').on('click', '.star', function() {
  let point = $(this).index();
  $('.star').each(function(index) {
    return index >= point ? $(this).addClass('selected') : 
    $(this).removeClass('selected'); //A
  });
  $('#rating').val($(this).data('rating'));
  console.log($('#rating').val());
});
```

```css
.rating {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 25%;
}

.star {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(112, 111, 111, 0.856);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.star.selected {
  color: #001628;
}

.star:hover,
.star:hover~.star {
  color: #e2334c;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 25px !important
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<input id="rating" name="rating" type="hidden" value="">
<div class="rating">
  <i class="star fa fa-star" data-rating="5" style='order:5'></i>
  <i class="star fa fa-star" data-rating="4" style='order:4'></i>
  <i class="star fa fa-star" data-rating="3" style='order:3'></i>
  <i class="star fa fa-star" data-rating="2" style='order:2'></i>
  <i class="star fa fa-star" data-rating="1" style='order:1'></i>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```